# Pixeldata curvefever collision

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

Soo, I am doing a remake of curvefever (http://curvefever.com/) using HTML5 Canvas however, I got the collision, but it collides all time, from the previous step:

http://jsbin.com/xenujaja/1/edit

Is there anyway to make it, **not** be able to collide by where it was in the last timestep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look ahead to be able to correctly test, otherwise, you'll always get a true answer.

Just use the regular cos/sin code to get a position ahead of current player :

```
// if dist is the distance ahead  
ahead.x = player.x + dist * Math.cos ( angle ) ;
ahead.y = player.y + dist * Math.sin ( angle ) ;  // !! and not - as you did
```

And no need to test a whole area, a single pixel test is enough, as you'll see on this fiddle : 
http://jsbin.com/xenujaja/2/edit?js,output

( top-left square now says no collision / collision )

```
function getCIDCol(pl, ctx) {
    next.x = player.x + Math.cos(player.a) * player.r ;
    next.y = player.y + Math.sin(player.a) * player.r ;

    var id = ctx.getImageData(next.x, next.y ,1,1 );

    return (id.data[3]) ; 
}
var next = {x:0, y:0 }; 

function update() {
    RAF(update);

    if (keys[39]) {
        player.a += player.t
    }
    if (keys[37]) {
        player.a -= player.t
    }

    player.x += Math.cos(player.a) * player.s
    player.y += Math.sin(player.a) * player.s        

    if (player.ht == null) {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) == 1) {
            player.ht = setTimeout(function() {
                player.ht = null;
            }, player.h)
        }
    }

  // draw collision status
    if (getCIDCol(player, ctx)) {
        ctx.fillStyle='#F00';
    } else ctx.fillStyle='#0F0';
   ctx.fillRect(4,4, 16,16);

    render()        
}
```